# Как увидеть на github не свои обновления?

Tags: git, github

Добавил возможность одному пользователю редактировать мои репозитории на гитхабе.

На своей странице, я могу просматривать только свои изменения. А где я могу увидеть изменения, которые были сделаны в моих репозиториях другими пользователями?

Comment: что именно вы подразумеваете под «редактированием»?

Comment: тут два варианта - либо человек ещё ничего не "редактировал" (не пушил"), либо он это сделал в своей ветке (переключаеся на нужную ветку и смотрим).

Comment: редактирование - другой пользователь может править исходники

Comment: у меня несколько репозиториев... хотелось бы сразу увидеть, что были до меня какие-то изменения, даже не залезая в репы, не то что выискивать ветки)))

Comment: можно настроить себе нотификации. Будет приходить на почту (или как настроите) https://help.github.com/articles/managing-notifications-for-pushes-to-a-repository/

Comment: хотя бы так... хотя тоже не полноценное решение... вдруг я месяц отдыхал, прихожу - что было и кто что делал, не на почте же искать )))

Comment: там можно прицепить свой скрипт. А он хоть смс будет отправлять.